# Can not find any scanners

Tags: 20.04, scanner, ubuntu-mate

I am trying out version 20.04.

I installed all required drivers for my Canon TS9120 scanner/printer using .deb files.

And also tried adding printer with system settings and add printer.

Document Scanner can not find any scanners.

And scangearmp2 can not find any scanners.

It worked find with 18.04?

Comment: Is the printer connected by USB or networked?  Which drivers did you install, the official Canon ones? Can you print, but not scan?

Comment: you can install your printer in wifi mode and see if this works.i had the same problem when i tried to install a hp printer/scanner in usb mode,the same printer/scanner worked fine on every ubuntu from 12.04 to 18.04 but not on 20.04 in usb mode but in wifi mode it works.

Comment: I can not find how to install it in wifi mode? @trond hansen

Comment: you can probably do this on your printer/scanner,i did not touch my pc at all when i set up mine,you can ask this as a new question here or take a look at canons help pages if you are unable to set up your printer/scanner.https://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/TS9100%20series/EN/UG/ug_p_02_01_03.html